# Comparing a character to a set of characters in Ada

Tags: comparison, character, range, ada, letter

I'm using Ada and getting and int, and I need to check if it was a character that was converted to an int by converting it back and testing it against a character. The problem is I don't wanna type

```
if intToChar(popped) = 'a' | 'A' | 'b' | 'B' | (etc.) 
then
```

I'm new to Ada, so I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this instead of typing out  52 ors. I've tried a few things, but no success.

I was wondering if I could use something like a character range 'a'..'Z' (also, does 'a'..'Z' get the whole alphabet? Or maybe 'A'..'z'?), but I know these are values, not actually characters when used in a type.

I could also make a function to check, but I only need to do this at one spot in the code, so a shortcut I'm missing here would be nice. I could also use a function that checks if a variable is a character, if that is included in Ada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found Ada.Characters.Handling.Is_Letter()

Comment: Good find. Make sure to thumb through the rest of the provided standard library ( http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A.html ) to see what other such goodies are available.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need maps for this:

```
Subtype Uppercase is Character Range 'A'..'Z';
Subtype Lowercase is Character Range 'a'..'z';

If C in Uppercase or C in Lowercase then
  ...
End if;
```

Of course for more complicated checks maps {or sets} are the way to go.